# Rationale for illegal immigration to Europe?

Tags: europe, illegal-immigration, asylum

I am trying to understand to what extent attempts to illegally migrate to Europe (EU,UK) are rational, or whether misinformation about the target countries is playing a crucial role. To clarify, asylum seekers with a chance to actually get asylum aren't covered by my question.

Based on having read a number of news articles including reports of interviews with people who've tried to migrate, were currently on-route, or were contemplating to try in the future, my current understanding is as follows:

- The typical motivation is a bleak situation in the country of origin. The person sees no hope of a decent future there, and is thus willing to undergo significant risks to have a shot at a happy and prosperous life. Corruption is a significant issue.
- The journey to Europe costs several thousand $/£/€.
- There is a general awareness of the deadly risks posed by crossing the Sahara/travelling through Libya/crossing the Mediterranean on a small boat/etc, which are deemed acceptable giving the bleakness of the status-quo and the hope for a better life in Europe.

What these articles tend to leave out is how this is supposed to work out once the person arrives at the target country. As they are fleeing a life-that-profoundly-sucks, not political persecution or a significant risk for their life, getting asylum seems out of the question. Without a work permit, it's probably difficult to get a decent job; and they'd be very vulnerable to exploitation. I'd expect that just earning back the costs for the journey is going to be a lengthy undertaking.

Am I missing something?

One single article (about Albanians trying to move to the UK) mentioned organized crime organizations pushing misinformation to prospective migrants about the opportunities in the UK in order to then exploit them as vulnerable illegal immigrants. However, neither this specific thing nor the more general question seems to be playing a prominent role in the political debate on the issue.

Comment: Hmmm I wonder if there are interviews with still-illegal immigrants that address this question.  Though that would be anecdotal, enough anecdotes do add up to information.

Comment: You are essentially seeing the crux of the illegal migration problem in Europe. The smugglers who take these people over the Mediterranean don't really care what happens afterwards, and the people themselves likely don't have a plan either. How could they? They have no idea what Europe even looks like

Comment: @Ccm *How could they?*  I dunno, maybe a family member or fellow villager contacting them?  They may have a harder time knowing if a  particular smuggler is trustworthy or not, but it's naive to assume no one has heard from *anyone* who has been to Europe.  Though sometimes people will also try to pass off as more successful than they really are.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Word of mouth and actually knowing what's it like are 2 entirely, completely different things.

Comment: @Ccm Something or somebody still gives the people an idea of the sunlit uplands of Europe being worth risking your life for, and the question is, where exactly that idea comes from.

Comment: @TooTea historically, ideas have a way of spreading around (in this case, probably smugglers advertise their services). But that still doesn't give them the correct knowledge about how things actually work in Europe. This is a contributing factor why some migrants never really manage to integrate and end up forming enclaves in poor neighborhoods, get tangled with other human traffickers and generally end up with less freedoms than they had in their source countries, while making the environment worse for everybody.

Comment: It's possible to live illegally for years, to work in the black economy (whether in sweatshops/businesses not following the law, doing gig work like deliveries, or criminal activities). I don't think it's possible to say whether someone would have a better life living in e.g. Somalia or illegally in London, which makes this question hard to answer as framed. And another complication is that coming from a war zone is a bit different than coming from somewhere more stable but still poor (you can't claim asylum purely on the basis of your country being at war, it requires persecution).

Comment: I think this needs edited to ask a real question with a factual answer, not just "Am I missing something?" to which the answer is almost certainly yes. There are certainly factual questions that could be asked about this issue, but at the moment the question fails to do that.

Comment: @StuartF The core question is in the first paragraph. The rest explains my current understanding of the matter.

Comment: .. because it works: https://www.nytimes.com/2023/10/01/magazine/economy-illegal-immigration.html?unlocked_article_code=1.ME0.dBy-.gu-XNAJLw5l4&smid=url-share

Comment: Even working illegally for €4/h (and even taking into account the high cost of living in Europe) would give most of the world's poorest billion (or three) a much better life than they currently have. (I think most people fortunate enough to have been born in a rich country--this might include OP--have trouble imagining this.)

Answer (score 2):

> What these articles tend to leave out is how this is supposed to work out once the person arrives at the target country. As they are fleeing a life-that-profoundly-sucks, not political persecution or a significant risk for their life, getting asylum seems out of the question. Without a work permit, it's probably difficult to get a decent job; and they'd be very vulnerable to exploitation. I'd expect that just earning back the costs for the journey is going to be a lengthy undertaking.

Firstly, many of those people do escape from war (like Syrians a few years ago) or from the conditions where lawlessness and poverty pose serious risk for life. There is some legitimate question in where/how they get a few thousand dollars/euro to pay for the trip (and how many immigrants actually do pay such a price.)

However, from a purely economic perspective, even working in Europe illegally is probably better than in most of the world. Indeed, [the poverty threshold as established by the World bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poverty_threshold) is:

> In September 2022, the World Bank updated the International Poverty Line (IPL), a global absolute minimum, to $2.15 per day (in PPP). In addition, as of 2022, $3.65 per day in PPP for lower-middle income countries, and $6.85 per day in PPP for upper-middle income countries. Per the $1.90/day standard, the percentage of the global population living in absolute poverty fell from over 80% in 1800 to 10% by 2015, according to United Nations estimates, which found roughly 734 million people remained in absolute poverty.

The following map from the quoted Wikipedia article shows the percentage of the population living on less than $1.90 per day:
[image]

Simple math: $1.90 per day correspond to about $730 per year (about 700 euro.)

On the other hand, here is the [map of median income in Europe](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Living_conditions_in_Europe_-_income_distribution_and_income_inequality) (not that median is not mean - half of the population earn more than median income):
[image]

And here is the map of [minimum wages in European countries](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-eurostat-news/-/ddn-20220128-2) - anyone working legally in western Europe earns in a month at least as much as the immigrants escaping poverty need to survive in a year:
[image]

Obviously, there are no data on how much one earns illegally, but it is likely comparable to the income earned when working legally - on the one hand, illegal employees are likely to be paid less, because of the risks taken by employer (and they are hired because they cost less). On the other hand, illegal labor is not taxed - so the illegal labor costs cheaper even when the salary is equal to a legal one.

Comment: "anyone working legally in western Europe earns in a month at least as much as the immigrants escaping poverty need to survive in a year:" Yes but the costs are so much higher - if you want to compare you need to balance local costs. It may be that you earn as much in a month in Europe as you need for a year in Madagascar but European higher rent, food, travel costs leave you with a much smaller disparity (not claiming there isn't still one, but the answer as it stands exaggerates).

Comment: @LioElbammalf what I didn't point out in the answer, is that there's a certain level of disparity that triggers massive migration. There's hardly any influx of illegal economic migrants from post-Soviet space, Turkey and other territories close to EU with lower, but still acceptable level of life.

Comment: This looks like a pretty solid answer.  While I agree that not taking into account comparative costs *overstates* the case, there are also factors *strengthening* this A.  For example, push come to shove, you will be getting free emergency health care in Europe - that's not something guaranteed in many poor countries.  You will also not be left to literally starve.  You do need to pay for heat in winter, which isn't typically a problem in source countries.  (But more and more source countries will be facing summer heat waves risks, annulling that).

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica regarding the comparative costs: 1) one does not necessarily adopt high standard of living typical of the host country (e.g., sharing apartment, walking or riding bicycle, not moving during vacations,  eating simple food, etc.) 2) one's family/extended family/village may stay back at home, and supporting them incurs little additional cost.

Comment: Oh, I agree there too.  However, one last thing to keep into account:  many immigrants who managed to pay those thousand dollar fees weren't necessarily on the bottom rung of society in their origin country - they may have had a maid for example - and there the comparison may swing the other way.